# How to use HP M209dw printer on LAN only (disconnect/block it from “phoning home” on the Internet)?

Tags: printing, privacy, ownership, hp, proprietary

I don't want my HP M209dw printer to chat with its corporate mothership any more. I just want to use the hardware I bought and have it work for me on my local network without complaining about the lack of a subscription or sign-in or whatever.

I remember seeing instructions for a way to do this (possibly using a USB connection to the router) but I can't find them any more.

To be specific, my PC runs Windows but can use WSL if needed.

Comment: What model is your router ?

Comment: Can't say I blame you, since HP is intentionally borking some printers. https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/09/hp-to-pay-eu-printer-customers-1-35-million-for-disabling-third-party-ink/ See: https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/comments/15wpsl4/block_hp_laser_jet_pro_printer_from_accessing/

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want my printer to chat with its corporate mothership any
> more.

This is not within your control (> 98%).

The printer has HP firmware and so, if connected, you cannot control what it natively connects to.

You might try sniffer software and see if you can determine the IP address that it goes out to and then consider blocking that in your firewall. That also may cause printer issues.